# Odoo error: return self.models[model_name] KeyError: 'res_groups_users_rel'

Tags: python-2.7, many-to-many, odoo, odoo-9, many-to-one

I need to make UI many2one dopdown list where I can identify users which depend to Manager group role.

Now I have dropdown field:

```
test = fields.Many2one('res.groups', 'Purchase request type', default=_get_users, track_visibility='onchange')
```

And I tried to write a function which can identify all users which depend to manager group role.

```
def _get_users(self):
    pickings = self.env['res_groups_users_rel'].search([('gid','=',61)])
    pickings_available = []
    for picking in pickings:
            pickings_available.append(picking)
    return pickings_available
```

And I got an error:

```
    return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: 'res_groups_users_rel'
```

I don't know how can I change this function and get value from amy2many relation.

I changed my function to:

def _get_users(self):
    pickings = self.env['res.groups'].browse(61).users
    pickings_available = []
    for picking in pickings:
        pickings_available.append(picking)
    return pickings_available

and field:

test = fields.Many2one('res.users', 'Some text', default=_get_users, track_visibility='onchange')

I logged function `_get_users` and get values: `[res.users(9,), res.users(65,)]`

But I still can't get these values on my test field dropdown. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get all users that belong to a group, why not do the following:

```
self.env['res_groups'].browse(61).users
```

On a side note, you might get an error, trying to assign a list as default value to a Many2one field.

Also you seem to be assigning users belonging to a group to a field that is specified to store reference to groups.

If you need to have a field to select a user that belongs to group with id 61, you can do the following:

```
test = fields.Many2one('res.users', 'Some description', domain="[('groups_id', 'in', [61])]")
```

Comment: Hello, I tied: pickings = self.env['res.groups'].browse(61).users  But then from my test field I got all the groups without filtering but not users.

Comment: You have designated the field to display groups (by defining it to reference `'res.groups'` model). If you would like to filter the groups, you should also provide a domain. If you would like it to display users, then you should make it reference your user model instead.

Comment: I edited my question. Make changes for my function but I still can't get the result I want. If I just change test field to: test = fields.Many2one('res.users', 'Some description', domain="[('groups_id)', 'in', [61])]") and I got an error: ValueError: Invalid field u'groups_id)' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: (u'groups_id)', u'in', [61]) on res_users (ctx: )>"

Comment: It works. But I can't understand a domain = "[('groups_id', 'in', [61])]". I found groups_id field in mail_channel_res_group_rel table. But how it  relates with res.users model fields I can't understand.

Comment: When a Many2many relation is defined, it is achieved with these helper (relation) tables. If you use raw sql, you will use this table to achieve what you want. Since the purpose of the ORM is to simplify things, you get all related models as object properties. For example, instead of making a bunch of joins, you can just do `partner.user_id.groups_id.id` for a `res.partner` record `partner`. As for the domain part, it is just a filter. With no domain, your `test` field will allow you to select from all users. With above domain only users having group id 61 in their `groups_id` field will show.